# Play Framework: No implicit format for Map

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.5, play-json

Using Play 2.5 I cannot seem to serialize a `Map[SomeCaseClass, String]`

```
case class SomeCaseClass(value: String)

implicit val formatSomeCaseClass = Json.format[SomeCaseClass]

Json.toJson(Map[SomeCaseClass, String](SomeCaseClass("") -> ""))
```

Errors with

> No Json serializer found for type
>   scala.collection.immutable.Map[SomeCaseClass,String]. Try to implement
>   an implicit Writes or Format for this type.

Unless i'm missing something obvious, there is an implicit format for that type immediately above.

If I try something more simple like:

```
Json.toJson(Something(""))
Json.toJson(Map[String, String]("" -> ""))
```

It works fine. What am I missing when using a `Map` with a more complex type e.g. `SomeCaseClass`?

Comment: It works for me - see https://scalafiddle.io/sf/9tbdZpk/0

Comment: @pme I wonder if its a scala/play version thing, i'm using play 2.5

Comment: it looks like - Scalafiddle uses 2.6 when I recall correctly. Anyhow, the format it generates is not what you want anyway;).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem here comes from json. Maps get converted to JSON objects which consist of key/value pairs. The keys in those objects `must` be strings.

So a `Map[String, T]` can get converted to a json object but not an arbitrary `Map[U, T]`.

Comment: Yep I think you're right, I swapped the key and value around and it works, thanks

Comment: Given my case class is just a wrapper around a String, can you think of any way I can get it to work?

Comment: The simplest way may be to just remove your case class

Comment: The reason I ask is I had hoped to substitute my case class with an Enum, so it would just serialize to a String

Comment: If you only want to write it, you could map your Enum values before writing to the corresponding strings: `mapToWrite.map { case (key, value) => (key.toString, value) }`

Answer (score 1):

@Jack Bourne is correct. A map is treated as a JsObject in play json and because of that the key must be serialisable to a string value.

Here is a sample code that you can use to define a map format

```
import play.api.libs.json._

case class SomeCaseClass(value: String)

implicit val formatSomeCaseClass = Json.format[SomeCaseClass]

Json.toJson(Map[SomeCaseClass, String](SomeCaseClass("") -> ""))

implicit val someCaseClassToStringFormat = new Format[Map[SomeCaseClass, String]] {
override def writes(o: Map[SomeCaseClass, String]): JsValue = {
  val tuples = o.toSeq.map {
    case (key, value) => key.value -> Json.toJsFieldJsValueWrapper(value)
  }
  Json.obj(tuples: _*)
}

override def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[Map[SomeCaseClass, String]] = {
  val resultMap: Map[SomeCaseClass, String] = json.as[JsObject].value.toSeq.map {
    case (key, value) => Json.fromJson[SomeCaseClass](value) match {
      case JsSuccess(someCaseClass, _) => someCaseClass -> key
      case JsError(errors) => throw new Exception(s"Unable to parse json :: $value as SomeCaseClass because of ${JsError.apply(errors)}")
    }
  }(collection.breakOut)
  JsSuccess(resultMap)
 }
}
```